# Web service to capture data and store in Another database table

Tags: php, json, web-services, rest, soap

There is a software for cinema booking.Its in php/mysql. I need to get the some details from their database table and store that details in another database table.This should happen every day.

The above is the task to do.How can i do that?

Comment: Either set up a cronjob or set up an event within the database to transfer the data.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue which can be answered in a few paragraphs. I would suggest you find a development forum (perhaps [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.